# Rails 2.2.2 Migration to Rails 3 - CSS Location

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am migrating a Rails 2.2.2 project to Rails 3 but I am seeing a lot of 404 errors:

```
 Started GET "/assets/b2b.png" for 172.20.140.52 at    2013-03-11 12:30:24 -0400
 Served asset /b2b.png - 404 Not Found (8ms)
 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/b2b.png"):

 Started GET "/assets/default.css" for 172.20.140.52 at 2013-03-11 11:57:29 -0400
 Served asset /default.css - 404 Not Found (5ms)
 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/default.css"):
```

In my Rails 2.2.2 project, all of my stylesheets were stored in 
**/var/www/my_app_directory/public/stylesheets/** so I just moved that over to Rails 3, which I think is the issue.

Where should I put all of my CSS for Rails 3 to be happy?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 3 introduced [assets pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) so you should move all stylesheets to

```
app/assets/stylesheets
```

and create `application.css` which should contain:

```
// require_self
// require_tree .
```

Comment: Great. Thanks for the link. Solved the issue per your instructions.